# Inspecting request entity before handing off to Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey

I'm using Jersey to build a RESTful service to replace an existing, legacy service.

The legacy request format requires that authentication credentials be passed in the body a POST request. This makes it awkward to validate the request (with Spring security) before passing the request to Jersey, because the POST body must be read to extract the authentication credentials, and then re-packaged before handing off to Jersey.

This means that, for every POST request, the request stream must be read, re-serialized, and then read again by Jersey `MessageBodyReader`s. I don't like this because it is inefficient. Ideally, what I'd like to do, is transform the incoming message to a canonical message format, authenticate it, and then pass that canonical format to Jersey. It doesn't seem like JAX-RS has support for that kind of thing.

Does anyone have an recommendations for ways to avoid this double-read of the request body? Any RESTful frameworks that allow me to use a custom, canonical message format instead of in `InputStream`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options here.

Easiest is to read the message body in and use it to check your credentials in a filter.  If you do this, however, you will need to set up an `InputStream` of the data so that you can pass it along to whatever downstream filters there may be (and eventually the message body reader).  Sounds like this is the way that you have been going, and I suggest that you stick with it.  You don't need to reserialize, as you have the raw input string and can just pass it along the `InputStream` without transforming it, and if the input is well-formed you might be able to avoid the full serialization as well.

Alternatively you could turn everything in to a canonical object of some description at the same time that you are checking the credentials and store this as a request variable which can be accessed by your resources.  Trouble with this is that you are fighting Jersey's way of doing things so I would not recommend it.  Your resource methods will look a little strange to the outsider, and your filter will need to know all about your model so the design is a bit topsy-turvy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree that the second option is awkward, I'll avoid it. The first option, the way I've been doing it, requires that I deserialize the message body twice: once during authentication, and once when Jersey passes it to the `MessageBodyReader`.

Comment: Hmm... are you using a generic object for the message body outside of the authentication piece, or does the message body always contain the same object?  If the latter then perhaps the second option wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: The format of the message body can vary quite a bit, unfortunately. One thing I was thinking of doing was implementing a canonical object that implements `InputStream`, and implement a custom `MessageBodyReader` that simply casts the `InputStream` to the appropriate canonical object. I don't like the idea of "fighting" Jersey, though. I think I'll either go with option 1, or look for another framework that suits my needs better. Ideally I'd like something that supports a little bit of enterprise patterns with RESTful routing.